# What exactly is longitudinal polarization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, waves, polarization, mesons

See the title.  I keep reading about longitudinal polarization in difference scenarios (muons, especially), however I have been unable to find a clear definition of what it is.  I would appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A wave which is *longitudinally polarized* is polarized along its direction of travel. For a particle, the longitudinal component of its spin is the component of its spin parallel to its momentum. This component is usually called the longitudinal polarization.

For a massless particle like a photon, there is no longitudinal polarization. Massive particles like muons can have a longitudinal polarization.

Comment: Much simpler than I thought.  Thank you!